# Optimizing Actionscript performance

Tags: optimization, actionscript, flare

I am setting out for a visualization project that will generate 1000+ sprites from dynamic data. The toolkit I am using (Flare) requires some optimization. I am trying to figure out some optimization techniques for Flash. How can I make Flash run fast when there are so many sprites on the stage, or maybe there is an optimization technique that doesn't involve generating so many sprites?

Answer (score 1):

One good way of doing is freeze animations which are not visible to the user. But the complication with this is that, you need to remember the state from which the animation has to resume or refers the animation based on the current state of the whole application. Since you have so many sprites generated, make sure that you group them logically. This would help in easily implement the freezing logic.